# Grails 2.3 controller method returns JSON gets null back in unit test

Tags: json, unit-testing, grails

Let me start out by saying that this exact same issue exists on Grails 2.2.  I am running Grails 2.2 at work on Windows 7 and at home I run Grails 2.3 on OSX 10.8.4 via a Homebrew install. The same issue happens in both cases.  My controller looks like this one:

```
package play

import grails.converters.JSON

class HelloJsonController {

    def greet() { 
        def greeting = new Greeting(greeting: 'Hey there')
        render greeting as JSON
    }
}
```

My POGO (used above) is simply this:

```
package play

class Greeting {
    String greeting
}
```

The unit test - which I know should fail but is failing for the wrong reasons is this:

```
package play

import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import spock.lang.Specification

@TestFor(HelloJsonController)
class HelloJsonControllerSpec extends Specification {

    def setup() {
    }

    def cleanup() {
    }

    void "test that the controller can greet in JSON"() {
        when: 'you call the greet action'
        def resp = controller.greet()
        then: 'you should get back something nice, like a pony'
        resp == 'pony'
    }
}
```

I expect this test to fail of course because the string 'pony' does not match what I am returning.  However, the failure I am getting is not due to this, it is because **null** is coming back.  Then if I run the app and go to the URL I get back json and the string I expect per Firebug tracing.  Now, I can fix the unit test by hacking the Controller to be like this:

```
def greet() { 
    def greeting = new Greeting(greeting: 'Hey there')
    greeting as JSON
}
```

This causes the expected output:

```
resp == 'pony'
|    |
|    false
{"greeting":"Hey there"}
```

However, if I navigate to the URL it fails with a 404 now.  The only "fix" I have found it to mock up the content handler for the controller for the unit test.  The documentation says this should all work... or implies it.

Should this type of controller be unit testable as originally written?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`render` writes directly to the reponse - see [here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/testing.html#12.1.1%20Unit%20Testing%20Controllers).

Try like this:

```
void "test that the controller can greet in JSON"() {
    when: 
    controller.greet()

    then:
    response.text == '{"greeting":"Hey there"}'
    response.json.greeting == "Hey there"  //another option
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  My mistake was to assume render returned its output to the caller and would be the last expression in my controller action.  So I thought I could assert on that value being returned.